# DUPLICATES_DETECTED:Use one of these records?

Tags: apex, data-import-wizard

I am importing accounts through the data import wizzard and am receiving the following error:

DUPLICATES_DETECTED:Use one of these records?:--

I am glad it is catching the potential duplicate, but I selected the "Add new, and Update Existing" contact and accounts feature through the data import wizard. Why is this not updating the record if it is recognizing that the record already exists in my CRM.

Is this something I can correct on my end?

Answer (score 1):

The Data Import Wizard and Duplicate Management match records based on different criteria.

When you use Data Import Wizard, you can select criteria to match existing records on:

[image]

These criteria are highly likely to be distinct from the Matching Rules you define in Duplicate Management. As a result, records that Data Import Wizard does *not* match (and hence attempts to create new) can still be blocked as potential duplicates by your Matching Rules and Duplicate Rules.