# Flow: Account record created then create custom object record and associated Account

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow

scenario:
I have an Account object and an custom object (Employee__c)

Note: Employee__c object has lookup field of Account object.

Whenever the Account record is created then create an Employee__c record and associated the Account record to the Employee__c

The flow should only fires only when the Account recordTypeName = 'Online'

I'm not sure how to filter out the recordTypeId and assigned to Account

Here is what I have done.

1. Create a variable in the flow to store the recordType Id
   [image]
2. Use Get Records to retrieve the record type Id
   [image]
3. Flow:
   [image]
4. My Account object config.
   [image]

Comment: In my Record Trigger Flow I don't know how to execute only when the RecordTypeName = 'Online'

Comment: Did you try filtering in the start condition using recordtypeid is as entry condition?

Comment: i do not want to hardcode the recordtypeid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Decision element you can able to check the account record type.

I have taken contact creation when account created as an example.

Follow the below steps:

1.Select the record trigger flow

2.choose the object and set the criteria when **a record is created**

3.select Optimize the Flow for: **Actions and Related Records**

4.choose the decision element.

Replace Record type name with **Online** as shown in the below screenshot

[image]

5. add the Create record element and assign the values as per your need.

Create employee record and link to account id as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

Final Flow out diagram:

[image]

Comment: I will post the new question but I'm getting this error `DUPLICATES_DETECTED: Use one of these records?. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. ` when I create the same recordtype account name

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/377048/flow-duplicates-detected-use-one-of-these-records

Comment: Can you check, is there any duplicate rules are existing on account object? Refer the https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293077/duplicates-detecteduse-one-of-these-records